# Trigger error: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statement cannot operate on Trigger.new or Trigger.old

Tags: apex

There are 2 Objects: Student master & BlackListed Candidates-----> Task

when record is created in student master if "PAN card" field in this Object is equal to the "PAN card" field in the blacklisted candidates Object,
then
pls update "background status" field in Student master Object as 'cant hire candidate'

Error:
BlackListedCandidateTrigger: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old Class.BlackListedCandidatePAN.BlackListPANCheck: line 26, column 1 Trigger.BlackListedCandidateTrigger: line 3, column 1

**Apex Class:**

```
public class BlackListedCandidatePAN {
    
    public static List<Black_Listed_Candidate__c> VarBlackList = new List<Black_Listed_Candidate__c>();
    public static List<Student_Master__c> VarStudentList = new List<Student_Master__c>();
    public static List<Student_Master__c> studentsToUpdate = new List<Student_Master__c>();
 
    public static void BlackListPANCheck(List<Student_Master__c> newStudentRecs){
        // Query the blacklisted candidates outside the loop
        VarBlackList = [SELECT Id, PAN__c, Phone__c FROM Black_Listed_Candidate__c];
        
        // Iterate over each student record
        for(Student_Master__c newStudentRec : newStudentRecs){
            // Check if the student's PAN card is blacklisted
            for(Black_Listed_Candidate__c blackListRec : VarBlackList){
                if(newStudentRec.PAN_Card__c == blackListRec.PAN__c){
                    newStudentRec.Background_Check__c = 'Candidate is blacklisted! We cannot hire!';
                    newStudentRec.Phone_Number__c = blackListRec.Phone__c;
                    studentsToUpdate.add(newStudentRec);
                    // Break the loop since a match is found
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        
        if(!studentsToUpdate.isEmpty()){
            insert studentsToUpdate;
        }
        }
       
    }
```

**Trigger:**

```
trigger BlackListedCandidateTrigger on Student_Master__c (before insert) {
 
        BlackListedCandidatePAN.BlackListPANCheck(Trigger.new);
    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you can't (and don't need to) do an insert or update to the records in a before trigger. Any changes you make to `Trigger.new` will be applied on the record when it is inserted or updated. (This applies even when you pass `Trigger.new` into a new method)

You will just need to remove the `insert` statement and do not need to add them to a list.

For example:

```
trigger ExampleTrigger on Student_Master__c (before insert) {
    Helper.doStuff(Trigger.new);
}

public class Helper {
    public static void doStuff(List<Student_Master__c> newStudents){
        for(Student_Master__c s : newStudents){
            s.Test_Field__c = 'Test Value';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but Background check field is still not getting auto populated as required

Comment: Have you tried debugging to work out what the issue is?

Answer (score 1):

The `insert studentsToUpdate;` is not necessary here since you're in a  `before` trigger and are making adjustments to the records in `trigger.new` (also true for stuff in `trigger.newMap` if you're in a `before update` trigger). Even if it were, you wouldn't be re-inserting records, you'd be updating them. Also, checking if a list is empty before performing DML achieves nothing (it's just a waste of code). DML on an empty list will not fail because the list is empty. Salesforce will also not count it against the DML statement limit for the transaction.

The error message may seem a little strange to you, as you're not doing `insert trigger.new`, but the important thing is that you're attempting to perform DML on the *same instances* of your `Student_Master__c` records that are in `trigger.new`. To help illustrate.

```java
// non-primitive, "reference" types are passed into methods by reference
// So if you call this like "myMethod(trigger.new)", then "myAccounts" is a reference
//   to trigger.new
public void myMethod(List<Account> myAccounts) {
    // assigning a list to another list maintains the reference
    List<Account> localReference = myAccounts;
    // as does using the copy constructor
    List<Account> copied = new List<Account>(myAccounts);

    // Using deepclone() (SObject lists only) breaks the reference, making independent copies
    List<Account> independent = myAccounts.deepClone();

    // Querying for records will create new, independent instances
    List<Account> independentQueried = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone FROM Account WHERE Id IN :myAccounts];

    List<Account> fromLoopReferenced = new List<Account>();
    List<Account> fromLoopIndependent = new List<Account>();
    for(Account acct : myAccounts) {
        // The loop variable is a reference
        fromLoopReferenced.add(acct);

        // cloning or using "new" creates an independent instance
        fromLoopIndependent.add(acct.clone());
        fromLoopIndependent.add(new Account(Id = acct.Id, Name = acct.Name);
    }
}
```

There are also other troubling aspects to your code. They aren't causing errors, but they're bad practice and would probably cause issues down the line.

- You aren't applying any filters to your blacklist query (and industry is moving away from the blacklist/whitelist terminology)
- You're using the bad nested loop pattern where you have `if(field1 == field2)` in the inner loop

In general, there should be no queries without a `WHERE` clause. Omitting that means you run the risk of having your query be "non-selective" and/or going over the query row governor limit.

The nested loop with `if(field1 == field2)` is just a massive waste of CPU time (which is another governor limit). If you had even just 200 "blacklist" entries, that inner loop could be processed up to 2,000,000 times!

A much, much better approach would be:

- Loop over the students, and gather the `PAN_Card__c` values in a list or a set
- Use that information to filter your "blacklist" query
- Loop over the results of that query, putting the records into a `Map<String, Black_Listed_Candidate__c>` where the key is `PAN__c`
- Finally, you can loop over the students one more time, and use `PAN_Card__c` to pull a value from the previously created/populated map (and `continue;` if the result of calling `.get()` on the map is null)

That would address both of the issues presented above. The maximum number of times records are looped over in that scenario is 20,200 (10k max DML rows in a transaction, which we loop over twice, plus the 200 "blacklist" records I used in my previous calculation). That's 2 orders of magnitude less work being done!